# How to store Java constants for use in building key value combinations

Tags: java, constants, hashmap

Let's say I want to store potential keys and potential values for those keys as constants.  How can I achieve this?  Or should I avoid it altogether?

This is the aproach that I thought of myself, but as you'll be able to see, it has an obvious downfall.

```
public static class Foo { 

    public static final String KEY = "foo" ; 

    public static class Values { 

        public static final String BAR = "bar" ; 
        public static final String HEY = "hey" ; 

    }

}

public static class Another { 

    public static final String KEY = "another" ; 

    public static class Values { 

        public static final String ONE = "1" ; 
        public static final String TWO = "two" ;
        public static final String THREE = "THREE" ;

    }

}
```

Which allows me to access these keys like so

```
miscellaneousMethod( Foo.KEY, Foo.Values.BAR )
miscellaneousMethod( Another.KEY, Another.Values.TWO )
```

However, I don't exactly want to write a separate static inner class for each key / possible-values pair.

**Is there a better way to store key value pairs as constants?**

I want to store them as constants for later comparison with generated hashmaps.  So that I can ask stuff like this:

`if( map.get( Foo.KEY ).equals( Foo.Values.HEY ) ) { /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: @Paul - I get a dynamicly generated hashmap.  And I'm trying to see if certain keys exist in the map. If they do, do they equal specific values?  I want to store them somewhere because I do compares with that information in numerous places.

Comment: I would just keep the HashMap in a utility class.  Make it a singleton and use static accessors to work with the private static HashMap.  For convenience you could have methods like `public static boolean hasValue(String key, String value)` (where the type of key and value match what's in your map) to check that the key has the specific value.

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you've figured out the right approach and can share a snippet of how you got around the problem @CrazyPenguin

Answer (score 6):

If they are all constants, you might use an Enum:

```
public enum ValueEnum {

    FOO("foo", "bar", "hey"),
    ANOTHER("another", "1", "two", "THREE"),

    ;

    private final String key;

    private final Set<String> values;

    private ValueEnum(String key, String... values) {
        this.key = key;
        this.values = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(values)));
    }

    public final boolean isInMap(Map<String,String> map) {
        if(map.containsKey(key)) {
            return values.contains(map.get(key));
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
if( ValueEnum.FOO.isInMap(map) ) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please avoid constants like that.  For constants use the Java enum type.  It compiles under the hood as classes so you get type safety, and you can also use them in switch statements.  It's nice to be able to add methods to them too.

There's a nice example here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

A longer discussion (with many examples) is here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html

Answer (score -1):

Put the constants in a `Map` and then make it unmodifiable using the method `Collections.unmodifiableMap()`.

Comment: This isn't how you actually handle constants, is it?

Comment: No, but then again this isn't your usual functionality for constants either. The top voted answer also uses `unmodifiableMap()`. I don't understand your objection.

Comment: bkent's answer is wrapped in an enum which gives it type safety as well as answering the poster's needs.

Answer (score -1):

If possible, can you not just specify these keys in an XML file and use Java XML binding (JAXB) to load them.

- you would avoid having to rebuild and deploy your code when and if the keys change.